# How find this equation all pairs of integers $(m,n)$ such that $m^6 = n^{n+1} + n -1$

Tags: number-theory

Find all pairs of integers $(m,n)$ such that $m^6 = n^{n+1} + n -1$

My try: If $n>1$ is odd, then  note $$\left(n^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)^2<n^{n+1}+n-1<\left(n^{\frac{n+1}{2}}+1\right)^2$$
so
$n$ can't be odd

But for $n$ is even  number,I can't

I know $$(m,n)=(1,1),(-1,1)$$
 is such this equation,maybe have other solution such this equation.

Thank you

Comment: Your argument seems incorrect. If you suppose n = 2k+1, of course n is not even.

Comment: I think you mean "m cannot be even"

Comment: Do you mean -1 mod 2?

Comment: I can see the following: 

If m is even, then n can't be even. Also: If n is even, m is odd.

Also: m=n=1 solves it, so n can be odd. Something is wrong in your assumption

Comment: $n$ can't be odd and greater than 1.

Comment: @aaaaa why not?

Comment: @Bernd precisely because of what the OP has proven. He bounded the LHS between two consecutive squares with an inequality that holds only when $n>1$, as he stated.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Thanks. Sorry, what is LHS?

Comment: Left Hand Side, although I now noticed it should be Right Hand Side (RHS)

Comment: $41,194754273881$ may be another pair but I am not 100% sure as the computer only have about 50 digits and I can sure there is 30 zero behind the dot.

Comment: the pair is not correct,the 194754273881 is $41^k$.